# ExpressJS/NodeJS - Iphone not setting cookies in header, works on android devices

Tags: android, ios, node.js, cookies, axios

I have a server side code that uses **express.js** to handle sessions and cookies;
for my client side code I used **axios** to help manage the cookies and sessions:

**server side code (express.js):**

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: ["www.1.com", "www.2.com", "www.3.com"],
    credentials: true,
    allowedHeaders: ['Origin', 'X-Requested-With', 'Content-Type', 'Accept'],
    methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
    preflightContinue: true
}))
app.set('trust proxy', 1)
app.use(cookieParser("cookie-secret"))
app.use(session({
    secret: "cookie-secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: process.env.NODE_EV==="production",
    store: MongoStore.create({
        mongoUrl: "url",
        autoRemove:'interval',
        autoRemoveInterval: 10
    }),
    cookie: {
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'none',
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
    }
}));
```

**client side code (axios):**

```
import axios from 'axios'

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    withCredentials: true,
});

export default instance;
```

**client side code (usage):**

```
import instance from '../axiosAPI';

useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchQR() {
      try {
        const response = await instance.get("url");
        setItems(response?.data?.data || []);
        setLoaded(true);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
    fetchQR();
  }, []);
```

When I ran the code on android devices it works fine; however once testing on Iphones it doesn't seem to work...

Upon checking the request sent from the client side, the cookie and session are both recorded, however it is not sending the cookie in the header:

frontend code:

request from Android/windows:

```
"headers": {
      "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "accept-encoding": "gzip",
      "accept-language": "en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8",
      "cdn-loop": "ye",
      "cf-connecting-ip": "1.1.1.1",
      "cf-ew-via": "15",
      "cf-ipcountry": "AU",
      "cf-ray": "7f95c282c5a72efa-MEL",
      "cf-visitor": "{\"scheme\":\"https\"}",
      "cf-worker": "serverbackend.com",
      "content-length": "18",
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "cookie": "connect.sid=gomgom",
      "host": "www.serverbackend.com",
      "origin": "www.1.com",
      "priority": "u=1, i",
      "referer": "www.1.com",
      "render-proxy-ttl": "4",
      "sec-ch-ua": "\"Not/A)Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Microsoft Edge\";v=\"115\", \"Chromium\";v=\"115\"",
      "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
      "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"Windows\"",
      "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
      "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
      "sec-fetch-site": "cross-site",
      "true-client-ip": "1.1.1.1",
      "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/115.0.1901.203",
      "x-forwarded-for": "2.2.2.2, 3.3.3.3, 4.4.4.4",
      "x-forwarded-proto": "https",
      "x-request-start": "1692483374752209"
    },

"session": {
      "auth": {
        "email": "new@new.new",
        "user_id": "63d61ea63b02b90e9fa6006b",
        "username": "newnew"
      },
      "cookie": {
        "expires": "2023-08-20T21:48:51.458Z",
        "httpOnly": true,
        "originalMaxAge": 86400000,
        "path": "/",
        "sameSite": "none",
        "secure": true
      }
    },
    "sessionID": "DQfeslKPa8nSiJ5zdaJCuSc2RzXtztRw"
}
```

request from Iphones:

```
"headers": {
      "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "accept-encoding": "gzip",
      "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
      "cdn-loop": "ye",
      "cf-connecting-ip": "1.1.1.1",
      "cf-ew-via": "15",
      "cf-ipcountry": "US",
      "cf-ray": "7f95c8cdb19e8214-IAD",
      "cf-visitor": "{\"scheme\":\"https\"}",
      "cf-worker": "serverbackend.com",
      "host": "www.serverbackend.com",
      "origin": "www.1.com",
      "referer": "www.1.com",
      "render-proxy-ttl": "4",
      "true-client-ip": "1.1.1.1",
      "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1",
      "x-forwarded-for": "2.2.2.2, 3.3.3.3, 4.4.4.4",
      "x-forwarded-proto": "https",
      "x-request-start": "1692483632436366"
    },
"session": {
      "cookie": {
        "expires": "2023-08-20T22:20:32.440Z",
        "httpOnly": true,
        "originalMaxAge": 86400000,
        "path": "/",
        "sameSite": "none",
        "secure": true
      }
    },
    "sessionID": "N5Mo3R9keK3coTYMmjoZVqxIUi18vM_g",
}
```

I am running the server side code on render(https://render.com/), and my client side code is hosted on (https://www.netlify.com/).

does anyone know what the issue is and can point me to the right direction?

Thank you so much for your time

Comment: Why are you setting `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` on a GET request?  Setting content-type on a request describes the format of the body you are sending with the request, but there is no body to be sent with a GET request, thus that header is meaningless on the request.  Perhaps not your main issue, but it could be interfering with CORs somehow.